# How to change size of jQuery Mobile Slider elements?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to make my jQuery mobile slider rails thicker. I also need to make the knob of the slider larger as well. I have visited other SO threads and tried to change the CSS rules of the slider. The class of the slider widgets has been set to jquerymobileslider.
Here is the relevant contents of a  tag within my index.html:

```
.jquerymobileslider .ui-slider {
    height: 50px;
}

.jquerymobileslider .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

However I see no changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default height is already 50px, try the following ensuring it's applied after the default CSS styles and see if you notice any visual changes:

```
.ui-slider-track {
    height: 75px;
}
.ui-slider-handle {
    height: 75px;
    top: 0%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, The track height worked well, but the code to increase the size of the handle did not work...

Comment: I got the handle size to work, I had to add !important after the handle height and also had to add an additional width rule to make the handle more rounded. In your code, what does the top: 0%; do to the handle?

Comment: @Gthoma2 I needed to add the top positing to vertically align the handle so it appears within the track for the default theme/Jquery Mobile 1.4.0. You may, or may not need it. So just experiment.